# Add rounded corners to shader

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I have following shader that renders two triangles and I want to make the corners rounded so that they don't look as "pointy".

```c
const float tipAngle = 45.0; // Angle of the triangle's tip

const vec3 XOS_BLUE = vec3(0.0, 0.705882352941, 0.905882352941);
const vec3 WHITE = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
const vec3 BLACK = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

const float BLUE_TRIANGLE_ANGLE = -90.0;
const float WHITE_TRIANGLE_ANGLE = 90.0;

vec4 drawTriangle(
    vec4 fragColor,
    vec2 fragCoord,
    float rotationAngle,
    vec3 color,
    vec2 offset,
    float scale
) {
    vec2 center = iResolution.xy / 2.0;

    vec2 vertex1 = vec2(0.0, -scale * iResolution.y);
    vec2 vertex2 = vec2(-tan(radians(tipAngle)) * scale * iResolution.y, scale * iResolution.y);
    vec2 vertex3 = vec2(tan(radians(tipAngle)) * scale * iResolution.y, scale * iResolution.y);

    vec2 triangleCenter = (vertex1 + vertex2 + vertex3) / 3.0;

    // Translate the vertices to the origin (0, 0)
    vertex1 -= triangleCenter;
    vertex2 -= triangleCenter;
    vertex3 -= triangleCenter;

    // Apply rotation around the origin
    float angleRad = radians(rotationAngle);
    vertex1 = vec2(cos(angleRad) * vertex1.x - sin(angleRad) * vertex1.y, sin(angleRad) * vertex1.x + cos(angleRad) * vertex1.y);
    vertex2 = vec2(cos(angleRad) * vertex2.x - sin(angleRad) * vertex2.y, sin(angleRad) * vertex2.x + cos(angleRad) * vertex2.y);
    vertex3 = vec2(cos(angleRad) * vertex3.x - sin(angleRad) * vertex3.y, sin(angleRad) * vertex3.x + cos(angleRad) * vertex3.y);

    // Translate the vertices back to the center of the triangle
    vertex1 += triangleCenter;
    vertex2 += triangleCenter;
    vertex3 += triangleCenter;

    // Translate the vertices to the world space by adding the center and offset
    vertex1 += center + offset;
    vertex2 += center + offset;
    vertex3 += center + offset;

    // Calculate barycentric coordinates
    vec2 p = fragCoord - vertex1;
    vec2 e1 = vertex2 - vertex1;
    vec2 e2 = vertex3 - vertex1;
    float d00 = dot(e1, e1);
    float d01 = dot(e1, e2);
    float d11 = dot(e2, e2);
    float d20 = dot(p, e1);
    float d21 = dot(p, e2);
    float invDenom = 1.0 / (d00 * d11 - d01 * d01);
    float u = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) * invDenom;
    float v = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) * invDenom;

    // Check if the pixel is inside the rotated triangle
    if (u >= 0.0 && v >= 0.0 && (u + v) <= 1.0) {
        return vec4(color, 1.0);
    }
    
    return fragColor;
}

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord)
{
   fragColor = vec4(BLACK, 1.0);
   fragColor = drawTriangle(
       fragColor,
       fragCoord,
       BLUE_TRIANGLE_ANGLE,
       XOS_BLUE,
       vec2(0.0, 0.0),
       0.25
   );
   fragColor = drawTriangle(
       fragColor,
       fragCoord,
       WHITE_TRIANGLE_ANGLE,
       WHITE,
       vec2(0.0, 0.0),
       0.25
   );
}
```

I thought about adding a parameter `float cornerRadius` to the `drawTriangle` function but I am quite new to GLSL and lack the knowledge to get the corners rounded.

This is what it looks like right now:

[image: current result]

And I want it to be rounded somewhat like here (ignore the gradient, transparency and shadow):

[image: expected result]

I did find some answers and examples around rounded rectangles, but not triangles. Rectangles really are just two triangles but I'm not quite sure how that would translate into my code above.